# Algorithm : why top level of this recursion tree is cn?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I'm reading the introduction to algorithm, and for the merge sort Cormen gives this recursion tree, he said we assume that n is exact power of 2. But I don't quite get why the time cost of the root level is `cn` ? n is the input size, it's not the time cost so it's strange to me.

[image: recursion tree]

Comment: The way I read it, it's the sum of the child nodes - at every level the total is `cn`.

Comment: At the root level, the array is divided into two halves, and recursive calls are made to sort each half. After the recursive calls, there's a merge step that combines the two halves into a single sorted array. That merge operation takes O(n) time.

Comment: There are n elements to process, and the multiplier c is being used to model a constant time (or number of constant-time operations) needed to process each element. This model is approximate, but it's very close and the best you can do without a detailed description of the machine that's doing the computation.  At each level, a recursive call is handling half the number of elements of its caller, but there are twice as many calls.